# When sharing a const across files using extern, why is extern needed on the definition?

Tags: c++

Page 60 of C++ Primer 5th edition talks about sharing const variables across files like so

```
//file_1.cc
extern const int bufSize = fcn();

//file_1.h
extern const int bufSize;
```

When would bufSize be defined and what is the purpose of extern on file_1.cc? I understand that file_1.cc would define it, but Page 45 of the same book says that providing an initializer for a variable overrides the extern, so why is it necessary to have extern on the const's definition?

Comment: Unlike C, a const in C++ defaults to internal linkage, in this case as if it had been declared static. extern is required to override this.

Comment: So extern will change the variable to external linkage, allowing it to be shared across files?

Comment: Yes. The alternative is to declare the const only in a header without extern. This is fine for a simple const (not a class) given a literal (eg `const int size = 5;`). But if a const in a header file is initialized from a function, the function will be called again for every source file that includes the header, which is inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the standard,

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of ... a non-volatile variable that is explicitly declared `const` or `constexpr` and neither explicitly declared
>   `extern` nor previously declared to have external linkage

So there is a special rule that variables at namespace scope have internal linkage when `const` or `constexpr` even if they would otherwise have external linkage. I'm not entirely sure why this rule exists but I suspect it's to allow the compiler to inline `const` variables and hence not allocate any storage for them at all. The `extern` specifier explicitly overrides this and makes the variable have external linkage again.

> providing an initializer for a variable overrides the extern

Now this is a bit different. By default a declaration of a variable is also a definition, but `extern` suppresses this so you can declare a variable without defining it (i.e. because its definition is in another translation unit). But if you have an initializer then it overrides the `extern` and the declaration once again becomes a definition. This isn't really related to the rules about internal and external linkage above.